# Can't download CXF artifacts on JBossFuse running on OpenShift

Tags: openshift, jbossfuse, fabric8

I have a **JBoss Fuse** running on **OpenShift Online** and I want to deploy there a **Camel-CXF** application.
I created a profile and attached it to a running container. When I added a `feature-camel` parent to this profile, the container was successfully restarted, but then I tried to add `feature-cxf` the container failed with the following errors:

> io.fabric8.agent.utils.MultiException: Error while downloading
>   artifacts
>
> java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty

When I tried to add any features related to cxf I had the same errors.

What can be the problem and how can it be resolved?

Thanks, Anton