# Openshift - Jboss Fuse 6 - Adding Apache CXF feature error

Tags: jboss, openshift, jbossfuse

I have created a Jboss Fuse catridge on openshift. Now, when I go adding apache-cxf feature to container, I receive below error:

Provision Exception:
    io.fabric8.agent.utils.MultiException: Error while downloading artifacts
    java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty

I have done lot of research online around this, but couldn't find a resolution. Duplicate of another similar issue: [Can't download CXF artifacts on JBossFuse running on OpenShift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089423/cant-download-cxf-artifacts-on-jbossfuse-running-on-openshift)